# angularjs code changes do not show up after browser refresh

Tags: angularjs, html, visual-studio-2013

Any time, I make code changes in .hmtl file or the .js file, the browser still renders the old code and my new code changes don't show up in the browser result.

For example, I add the following 2 lines of code in .html file.

```
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="controls readonly">
            {{profile.FirstName}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
        <div class="controls readonly">
            {{profile.LastName}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then I do the following:

1. In VS2013, right click on my project and view in browser (IE or Chrome).
2. Login to my application.
3. Go the respective page and I see the rendering of the old html file. I do not see the newly added 2 div elements rendered at all.
4. I even hit f5 to refresh the browser but still no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Hit F12 in your browser to bring up the Developer Tools. Disable the Cache. Reload your page.

Comment: I can not find option in IE in dev tools to disable the cache

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083239/what-happened-to-always-refresh-from-server-in-ie11-developer-tools

Comment: Where is the option to disable the cache?

Answer (score 26):

Besides using Dev Tools to make sure the cache is disabled, you can edit your `Web.config` file and tell IIS to not cache your Angular files:

```
<configuration>

  <!-- Disable IIS caching for directories containing Angular templates and scripts -->
  <location path="app">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache"/>
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>

...
</configuration>
```

My Angular root directory is `app/`. You may need to modify according to your file structure.

Comment: Wow... this saved me!  I can't tell all of my customers to force chrome to refresh, and this fixed it!

Answer (score 10):

TypeScript only!

In tsconfig.json add…

```
"compileOnSave": true,
```

Comment: Where in the file? under what label?

Answer (score 5):

Try disabling your cache with Dev Tools:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/settings#general

Comment: If security issues were blocking access to your network resources, would you suggest disabling the firewall? Is that a "solution"?

Comment: @RickO'Shea What? These two topics aren't even remotely comparable. This question & answer(s) are discussing disabling browser _caching_ in a sandbox environment, during _development_ - so that the developer can see their changes. This is standard procedure when doing front-end development. It's quite literally equivalent to doing a hard-refresh (`ctrl+shift+R` in Chrome) every time, instead of a normal refresh. Nothing is blocking access to the resources, it's simply that cached versions are being loaded.

Answer (score 4):

Open devTools in chrome and select Network tab, In Network tab Un-check the Disable cache and reload the page.

Comment: None of the answers tell exactly how to do it in chrome browser, this answer is perfect for chrome.

Comment: @harry_42 I thought this would work, but for some reason, it isnt.  I'm using angularJS on my local and for some reason when I made an edit in the `angular.js` file in `bower_components/angular` folder, the change is not being reflected in the UI

Answer (score 3):

For me, none of the previous answers worked. I was using Chrome, and the only way I was able to view the update was by opening an incognito window. My regular browser window, for some reason, just will not get the latest assets.

I have tried clearing my cache, disabling cache on devtools, and hard refresh, to no avail. The only way I was able to fix it was by clearing the DNS cache. Here's a link with more details:

[How to Clear the DNS Cache on Computers and Web Browsers](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227988627-Clearing-the-DNS-Cache-on-Computers-and-Web-Browsers)

---

Using command line, here's how you go about doing it:

**Windows 7 & Earlier**

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

**Windows 8**

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

**OSX (Yosemite, El Capitain, and Sierra)**

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the aspnetcore enviroment variable from production to development. From the [official website](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/):

... set an environment variable to tell ASP.NET to run in development mode:

- If you’re using PowerShell in Windows, execute $Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"
- If you’re using cmd.exe in Windows, execute setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development", and then restart your command prompt to make the change take effect
- If you’re using Mac/Linux, execute export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

If you are in linux, you might have to do it as a superuser. i.e.

`sudo export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`

The value of the variable may revert back to `Production` after re-booting. If you want to work with several environments, I suggest you define them in the `launchSettings.json` file:

```
{
      "iisSettings": {
      "windowsAuthentication": false,
      "anonymousAuthentication": true,
      "iisExpress": {
         "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:40088/",
         "sslPort": 0
      }
   },
     "profiles": {
       "IIS Express": {
          "commandName": "IISExpress",
          "launchBrowser": true,
          "environmentVariables": {
              "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
          }
       },
       "IIS Express (Staging)": {
          "commandName": "IISExpress",
          "launchBrowser": true,
          "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
         }
       }
     }  
   }
```

Read about environments [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments):

Answer (score 2):

In chrome press F12>go to network tab> disable cache

[image]

Answer (score 2):

deleting the dist folder from clientApp folder from source resolve my issue and it started auto refresh again

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use Browserlink in Visual Studio 2013 to automatically reload the page

http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link

Answer (score 1):

You need to run command `yarn webpack:build` to recompile your client code. Otherwise modifications/updates in `.HTML`, `.json`, `.ts` files will not be reflected.

Answer (score 1):

I simply deleted the dist folder in Visual Studio and it auto refreshed again.

**** this was for Angular 7 ***

Answer (score 1):

Just right click on the page reload button on the browser and choose "Empty cache and Hard Reload"

Comment: This works, if you run app locally like me

Answer (score 1):

In my case issue inside Angular.json file `"deployUrl"`: should be relative path Like `"/support/yourpagenam/bundle/dist/"`
Hence any changes made in Angular files are not reflecting to Browser.

Answer (score 0):

### **Problem**

- Client-side (Browser) caching of static files in dev enviornment
- Server-side (IIS Express) caching of static files in dev enviornment

### **Solutions**

***`For Client-side (Browser) caching of static files in dev enviornment`***

- Web.Config/ApplicationHost.config Approch: Web.config Approach
  suggested by @NateBarbettini above. Please note that this approach is
  also can be applied to 'Applicationhost.config' instead of web.config
  file.
- "Always Refresh From Server" in IE as suggested above by @Phil Degenhardt. Please find screenshot below.
  [image]
- Navigate to source file location in browser address bar: Try to navigate to the JavaScript file in question by typing the address. It will show you JavaScript file contents. Once you do this, file gets updated.So you can again go back and try to navigate to proper landing page of your application. This time, you will see you get latest JavaScript code getting executed.
  e.g. If you have problem with not updating 'app/home/home-account.js'. Then in browser navigate to `'http://[your-host/localhost]:[specified port of your application]/app/home/home-account.js`. This will show you the contents. Then again navigate to your application's home page i.e. in this case `'http://[your-host/localhost]:[specified port of your application]/'`

***`For Server-side (IIS-Express) caching of static files in dev enviornment`***

- visit IIS Express appcmd commandline utility. In my case, appcmd is located in "C:\Program Files(x86)\IIS Express\appcmd.exe" this path. Then use `SITE list` and `SITE delete` command to remove temporary files cached in iisexpress.
- There is also one solution which is specific to IE mentioned here: 
  [Visual Studio 2013 caching older version of .js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739434/visual-studio-2013-caching-older-version-of-js-file)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of cache stored by the browser. Before running your application you can delete cache and cookies stored by your browser.

Answer (score 0):

**Set HTTP Response headers to expire content through IIS manager.**

1. Open **HTTP Response Headers** module for you web application
2. Click **Set Common headers** in the **Actions** pane

[image: Set HTTP Response headers to expire]

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache

Answer (score 0):

I opened link in Incognito mode since in that mode cache is disabled and Voila it worked.