# Angularjs 2 - Updating template or component does not update the UI

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript2.0, angular-components

I am coming from `angular 1` background where everything worked so smoothly and having some serious issues even making a basic application work in Visual Studio with `angular 2`. I created an empty project in visual studio and followed the "5 minute tutorial" very carefully. It came to the point where it started working finally but I observed an issue with updating the UI when I change the template in `app.component.ts`, nothing is being picked up on the browser. I had restarted and rerun the files but still the old output is being presented on the browser.

Following is my code:

In `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

`Systemjs.config.js`:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

My `index.html` has the following contents

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

      <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

In `app.module.ts`, I have

```
import { NgModule }      from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { AppComponent }  from "./app.component";
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

In `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: "<h2>Initiating {{angularVersion}}</h2>"
})
export class AppComponent {
    angularVersion = "Angular2.0";
}
```

and finally in `main.ts`, I have:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

This displays the output as `"Initiating Angular2.0"` when I set `index.html` as startup file in visual studio 2015 and run the project. My problem is, even if I update angularVersion variable to 2.1 or change anything else (from h2 to p etc) and rerun the file, It would still present me `"Initiating Angular2.0"`. Even hardcoding the `Template` won't update anything. I don't have any idea what I am doing wrong but it has started to frustrate a lot now. Any help please?

Comment: Are you sure that your ts files are compiling newly after saving? You just can check your `app.component.js` file

Comment: delete all js(compiled in app folder) files and give it try

Comment: Strangely enough when I run it using 'npm start', it works! But doesn't when I run from within the visual studio, typescript compiler doesn't generate the updated (compiled) javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hit F12 in your browser to bring up the Developer Tools. Disable the Cache as shown below

[image]

Secondly, I had to add this section just above  tag in web.config to disable cache

```
<location path="app">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache"/>
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Source: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311542/angularjs-code-changes-do-not-show-up-after-browser-refresh)

Comment: How should it work in production mode? We can't asks users to change browser settings on one hand, while still wanna keep caching on the other hand.

Answer (score 0):

I changed in [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

`compileOnSave` value from `false` to `true` and it worked for me.