# Changes in HTML not reflected in browser

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, asp.net-core, angular6

EDIT:
From what I am seeing, this is extending past a single project and must involve how I am handling building/running a project:

NEW BEHAVIOR,
I download the original project that I am basing my project off, in .Zip form
I extract the file and open the solution.
I click run and the project begins to build.
A browser opens up and displays my previous project. (a completely different solution)

*So I am creating a web application using Angular 6, net core 2.1, ef core 2.1...
I had built the front end, however--now the behavior that I am experiencing is that when I change any of my HTML code, the changes are not reflected inside of the browser.

Some things I have tried:
 1. Comment everything out.  Effect:  Nothing changes in browser.
 2. Change the filename of the HTML.  Effect: breaks the web application.
 3. Change filename back to normal, delete all html code.  Effect:  Application working again, still showing old content.

 4. Clean browser cache.  Effect: None
 5. Force refresh (Control f5).  Effect: None.
Does this sound familiar to anyone?*

Comment: While still in VS or after being published?

Comment: Hmm.  I build and run, and a browser pops up to the application.  This browser is what is not changing.

Comment: Are you sure you're going to the right page? Have you tried other browsers? What html did you change vs what you're seeing. Are you seeing/not seeing these changes in rendered content or are you viewing the html raw through developer mode in the browser(s)?

Comment: I've tried multiple browsers, I've tried disabling cache.  
I am viewing rendered content.  I have the whole page in like a home.component.html and what I am doing is literally deleting all of it (like control a, backspace) -- rebuilding, and then running on chrome and the content that I just deleted is still rendered.

Comment: I hate to say it, but I don't think you're running/editing what you think you are. If you've tried all that and it's not showing your edits, then you must be working on the wrong view. Multiple browsers removes any hint that it's a cache issue or even a browser issue.

Comment: did you check your launchSettings.json ? May be it open a site on wrong location, or you have a wrong dns config if you do no start on the localhost. Did you delete generated files in wwwroot ?

Comment: did you try to build de CientApp with angular-cli : `ng build` ?

Comment: @gilliduck If that is the case--why does changing the file name cause it to have a "Cannot Get /" error?

Comment: @aguafrommars
`code`
{
  "iisSettings": {

    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/WebPortal.Web.UserInterface",
      "sslPort": 0
    },
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5690/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Run": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8090;https://localhost:8095"
    }
  }
}
`code`

Comment: A "Cannot Get /" error is generaly because your angular app does not compile, read the output in VS

Comment: Hmm.. Okay.  I understand the compile error at least.  but I still haven't figured out what exactly is causing this behavior.  it's not just one html file either.  if I change any of the components html, the behavior remains the same.

Comment: If you have an compilation issue, it's possible that angular-cli doesn't update your output files. Fix your compilation issue first

Answer (score 2):

Hit F12 in your browser to bring up the Developer Tools. Disable the Cache. Reload your page.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28311558/10397183)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however--this is not the problem.  Attempted in Chrome.