# Angular 10 Browsers Do not Reflect any Code Changes

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm aware there are multiple questions regarding the topic. I have tried everything from.[This Qeustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311542/angularjs-code-changes-do-not-show-up-after-browser-refresh) Every single answer.

- Disabled Chace in Browser/App
- ASP.Net Settings
- npm cache clear --force

```
/*Verify Result */
Cache verified and compressed (~/.npm/_cacache):
Content verified: 0 (0 bytes)
Index entries: 0
Finished in 0.019s
```

- Deleting Dist/Rebuilding Application
- Adding "compileOnSave": true,  To tsconfig.json...

my NG serve Builds on http://localhost:4200/

There are 0 Changes being indicated by my browser from logs -> Alert Text changes in the code.

Console Reflects no changes, neither alerts or displays such as moving my html around abit.
Im returning to this project after a long time away from it. I Believe The last build I did to dist was in Production Not sure if this affects things.
My Environment is set to false for Production but Environment.prod -> Production = True.
(Not familiar with production not even sure what I changed with that build to get it into production). I do get "Angular is running in development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable production mode." In Console However

Not sure if anyone has encountered this recently? And can share how they resolved it?

Version Listings Below incase needed:

```
Angular CLI: 10.0.8
Node: 12.14.1
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 10.0.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... localize, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/core               10.0.8
@angular-devkit/schematics         10.0.8
@angular/cdk                       10.2.7
@angular/cli                       10.0.8
@angular/fire                      6.1.4
@angular/material                  10.2.7
@angular/material-moment-adapter   11.1.1
@ngtools/webpack                   10.0.8
@schematics/angular                10.0.8
@schematics/update                 0.1000.8
rxjs                               6.5.5
typescript                         3.9.7
webpack                            4.43.0
```

Adding more Details

The application Creates Reservations on a Calendar for a B&B Spot.
I can create a new Date but Previous Code that Checked for Double bookings aren't responding.The Alert that Tells the user it was a Success Doesn't get the updated text. But the new Entry Reflects on the Calendar I can instantly See it DB Entries are created as well. But cant see any Current changes made breakpoints dont hit either its almost as if im running an entirely different version of the application.

I have however checked there are no extra copies of the app anywhere near the same folder. Incase the CLI was booting the wrong one somehow. At a total loss

Edit: I ended up having to recreate the entire project to resolve this.

Comment: Are you using `@angular/pwa` or a service-worker?

Comment: Neither. Or at-least to the best of my knowledge i'm not using pwa/Cant find any ref to it on the app as well. 100% sure not using any Service workers my self might be a package thats using it tho.

Comment: Removed all Service Workers and disabled them